# Law vs Breed: why didn't Law use room to remove collars?

Tags: one-piece

Law's room ability is a very strong technique, and he can use it to slice whatever he wants.  Why doesn't he use it when fighting against Breed to remove collars from other animal and chopper?

I don't know the chapter but it's on episode 626.

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ePRlqLi-bUE) is a YouTube link.

Comment: you should at least had mention chapter or episode, it would be easier to look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a filler episode which is not taken from source material (i.e. manga). The fillers are just to extend time for the anime so that it does not catch up to the manga.

This happens in Naruto quite a lot and One Piece has only three filler arcs, so don't think too much about that episode, as it is there only to extend time

Comment: One Piece currently has 12 filler arcs but that is still not really that many considering how long the show has been on the air.

Comment: and the plus with OP filler arcs is that they mosty happen between arcs, so no breaking of story

Answer (score 1):

**He was waiting for the right time**. He was waiting until he got enough intel on the enemy before making his final move. If he spoiled the surprise early on, Breed could have counter-acted accordingly and might even have been able to re-attach the collars and order Law to never use his Devil Fruit again. Law didn't know Breed's full power yet at that time and just playing along. Remember how he only pretended to attack Luffy. Law was wearing ear-plugs and he wasn't under Breed's control at that time. He willingly attacked Luffy pretending to obey.

Law did the same thing on Punk Hazard, where he waited to remove the handcuffs when everyone was caged by Caesar. He didn't want to let his enemy know he was free to move about. He waited until he was out of sight, letting the enemy (Caesar) think he was defeated, giving him a lot of space and time to freely move about preparing his final counter attack.

Finally, I think Law is incapable of actually removing the collars, since he didn't actually removed them himself, even when he shambled to the submarine and had plenty of time to do so.